# how to make eevee ocean simulation wirh proper display and render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

so yeah, i made ocean scene via cycles tutorial. 
material preview looks good
[image]

but eevee render looks ugly.

[image]

i might did some mistakes in values but it doesn't matter for me rly, i just wonder how i can recreate material preview ocean in eevee render

shading on ocean 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're using the same hdri for the background.

Comment: in material preview hdri have no affect